# I can't see install Ubuntu alongside windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

When i try installing Ubuntu alongside Windows, I see only 2 options: One is to erase all data and install Ubuntu, and the other one is "Something else". I can't see an option to install alongside Windows 10.

Comment: First off, do you have Windows 10 installed on this current machine on which you're trying to Install Ubuntu??

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue, but there is a way to do it.

I choose "something else" and manually set up the partitions and mount points, **making sure I do not remove windows** (If there is no free space, shrink your windows partition but it is important to note that there are some safe practices before shrinking a windows partition! Firstly [Disable Hibernation File](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/920730) then [Disable the Page File](http://www.howtogeek.com/126430/htg-explains-what-is-the-windows-page-file-and-should-you-disable-it/) re-enable them AFTER shrinking!)

After I install Ubuntu, I am not able to boot into windows (Which is okay, there's a fix for that!) 
I sign in, and run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and then it works fine.

This only happens for me on some systems, on one system it only happened when I did not shrink my windows partition to allow space for Ubuntu first.

Good luck!